# Image between text in Django

Tags: python, django, blogs

I'm trying to figure out how I can place an image between text in a blog post in Django. I first thought of using something like the urlize filter ({ blog.body | urlize }) that would allow me to include a link for the image on the text body and then render the image on the post, but alas there is no filter for that. Or at least not that I know of.

I then realized it would be much more preferable if I could place the image inside the admin panel itself, in the form of an inline command, like it is done here:
https://pythonhosted.org/django-inline-media/

What is an easy implementation of this that wouldn't require me using the whole package there? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use the safe filter and use an img tag between your text.

For eg text added in your admin panel can go like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
<img src="">
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu 
fugiat nulla pariatur.
```

Now let's assume that you have passed this text under the name txt in the context dictionary in your views.py file. Then this text can be rendered as follows:

```
{txt | safe}
```

This way you can add an image anywhere you want in the text and dynamically render it.

Comment: You are awesome! It worked perfectly, exactly what I needed!

Comment: Glad I could help :)